# ng-click stops working when using a kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to get a `ng-click` event to fire correctly when integrating the Angular Kendo UI.

The following [Plunker shows a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yZcFLwZHinkdaDKHvCKV?p=preview), click the button `click me` and a modal window appears, however if I add the `kendo-grid` attribute to line 18 of index.html then the pop up does not work. e.g. changing:-

```
<table>
```

to:

```
<table kendo-grid>
```

Then the modal popup does not work. I suspect that when the grid is rendered then angular loses the binding. Not sure how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the angularjs-kendo labs master file does not support command binding and a [couple of issues](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/issues) have been raised.

Basically you need to take the [javascript](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/blob/compile-kendo-grid-rows/build/angular-kendo.js) from the [compile-kendo-grid-rows](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/tree/compile-kendo-grid-rows)

See [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VDrv8RQGT4tnKdoubBfh?p=preview).